# Lookup app.config element list by name

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

I want to retrieve settings from my app.config based on the name.

```
  <jobs>
    <add name="Name" sftpName="sftp" jobName="jobName"/>
    <add name="Name2" sftpName="sftp2" jobName="jobName2"/>
  </jobs>
```

I want to be able to look up by name.

I have created a `ConfigurationSection` for jobs but I can't seem to get it to give me the Name, sftpName and jobName, based on the name.

This will be deserializing into a class afterwards.

Is there a way in .NET I can autogenerate something?

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if it helps, I have checked it on my system and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can achieve this is by having a collection:

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace SerialApp
{
    public class JobSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("jobs", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        public JobCollection Jobs
        {
            get
            {
                JobCollection hostCollection = (JobCollection)base["jobs"];
                return hostCollection;
            }
        }
    }

    public class JobCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        public new JobConfigElement this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                if (IndexOf(name) < 0) return null;
                return (JobConfigElement)BaseGet(name);
            }
        }
        public JobConfigElement this[int index]
        {
            get { return (JobConfigElement)BaseGet(index); }
        }
        public int IndexOf(string name)
        {
            name = name.ToLower();

            for (int idx = 0; idx < base.Count; idx++)
            {
                if (this[idx].Name.ToLower() == name)
                    return idx;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
        {
            get { return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap; }
        }
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new JobConfigElement();
        }
        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((JobConfigElement)element).Name;
        }
        protected override string ElementName
        {
            get { return "job"; }
        }
    }

    public class JobConfigElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        public JobConfigElement() { }

        [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)this["name"]; }
            set { this["name"] = value; }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("sftpName", DefaultValue = "sftp")]
        public string SftpName
        {
            get { return (string)this["sftpName"]; }
            set { this["sftpName"] = value; }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("jobName", DefaultValue = "jobName")]
        public string JobName
        {
            get { return (string)this["jobName"]; }
            set { this["jobName"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Add following in .config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="JobSection" type="SerialApp.JobSection, SerialApp" />
  </configSections>
  <JobSection>
    <jobs>
      <job name="Name" sftpName="sftp" jobName="jobName"/>
      <job name="Name2" sftpName="sftp2" jobName="jobName2"/>
    </jobs>
  </JobSection>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

And call it simply as:

```
JobSection jobs = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("JobSection") as JobSection; 
if (jobSection != null)
{
    JobCollection jobCollection = jobSection.Jobs;
    var job = jobCollection["Name"];
    var jobName = job.JobName;
}
```